# OIDC - at_hash validation

Tags: openid-connect

I'm trying to get some clarification on the definition of the at_hash from the open id specs.

> Access Token hash value. Its value is the base64url encoding of the
>   left-most half of the hash of the octets of the ASCII representation
>   of the access_token value, where the hash algorithm used is the hash
>   algorithm used in the alg Header Parameter of the ID Token's JOSE
>   Header. For instance, if the alg is RS256, hash the access_token value
>   with SHA-256, then take the left-most 128 bits and base64url encode
>   them. The at_hash value is a case sensitive string.

**hash of the octets of the ASCII representation of the access_token value**

This is the part I'm confused about.

Does this mean we should hash the whole access token

OR

Should we decode the access token and just hash a single field like the JTI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the pseudocode would be:

`getBase64UrlString(getLeftHalfOfArray(getSha256Bytes(getAsciiBytes(accessTokenJwtString))))`

Example C# implementation here:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/3.1.3/src/IdentityServer4/src/Configuration/CryptoHelper.cs

In `CreateHashClaimValue()`

Comment: So this means we would be hashing the entire access token jwt string, right?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the **whole Access Token as a string**, so without trying to decode anything, since the Access Token format is non standardised anyway.

Then for completeness: convert that string to binary data using ASCII encoding, hash that binary using the appropriate Hash Alg, and take the left-most half of the result.